# Multiprocessing getting stuck with ARMAX while refitting

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to train multiple time series models using the below code in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import multiprocessing
import tqdm

train_dict = dict() # A dictionary of dataframes
test_dict = dict() # A dictionary of dataframes

def train_arma(key):
    endog = list(train_dict[key].endog)
    exog = list(train_dict[key].exog)
    
    fut_endog = list(train_dict[key].endog)
    fut_exog = list(test_dict[key].exog)

    model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(endog, order=(2, 0, 2), exog=exog,
                               enforce_stationarity=False,
                               enforce_invertibility=False).fit()
    predictions = list()
    yhat = model.forecast(exog=[fut_exog[0]])[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)

    for i in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(range(len(fut_vol))[:-1]):
        model = model.append([fut_vol[i]], exog=[fut_exog[i]], refit=True) #code gets stuck here
        predictions.append(model.forecast(exog=[fut_exog[i+1]])

    return predictions

secs = list(train_dict.keys())
p = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
output = p.map(train_arma, secs)
p.terminate()
```

When `len(endog) == 1006`, the code keeps getting stuck on the 17th iteration in the for loop. If I decrease the endog by 20, then it gets stuck on 37th iteration.

There are some other things I have tried already:

1. Passing dataframes directly instead of letting the function acess train_dict and test_dict from outer scope.
2. Reducing the number of maximum processes in multiprocessing.
3. Shuffling my input list.
4. Defining a new class instance in the for loop while appending the values from fut_endog and fut_exog lists in endog and exog lists respectively.

I did a `top` in my linux terminal and the observed the cpu usage while processes were getting created and executed. Initially when the processes spawn, they use up cpu and when the processes gets stuck %CPU allocation becomes 0.

There are some instances when the code does work:

1. When I call the function directly, without multiprocessing, it works. But using multiprocessing even with `processes = 1` makes the code stop.
2. When I don't pass any exogenous variable and train a simple ARMA model it works.

I am using statsmodels v0.12.1 and python version is 3.7.3. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue must be due to usage of tqdm alongside multiprocessing.

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/461 addresses this issue.

I resolved it by using

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.get_lock().locks = []
```